# Функция onscroll JS. Как убрать подергивания?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, mouse-event, mousewheel

Имеется следующий код:

```
  $(window).scroll(function (e) {
      var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

dtcur = new Date();
dtcur=dtcur.getTime();
dtdiff = parseInt((dtcur-dt));
    var currentscrolled=parseInt($(this).scrollTop());
var browswidth = document.body.clientWidth+17;
var item1=parseInt($('#item-1').offset().top);
var item2=parseInt($('#item-2').offset().top);
var item3=parseInt($('#item-3').offset().top);
var item4=parseInt($('#item-4').offset().top);
var item5=parseInt($('#item-5').offset().top);
var item6=parseInt($('#item-6').offset().top);

if(browswidth<1100)
  {}
else{
  if((currentscrolled>item1&&currentscrolled<item2)||(currentscrolled>=item6) || currentscrolled==0)
    {$('#navbar').hide();}else{$('#navbar').show();}
if(dtdiff>1000 &&flag==0){



if(currentscrolled<0){$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
}else{}

if(currentscrolled>scrolledlast){

if(posmax>pos){
  pos++;
}
var blockps = $('div.bg--'+pos).offset().top;
blockps=parseInt(blockps);
scrolledlast=currentscrolled
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:blockps},800);

  }
  else{
if(posmin<pos){
  pos=pos-1;
}
if(pos==1){
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);

}else{
   var blockps = $('div.bg--'+pos).offset().top;
blockps=parseInt(blockps);
scrolledlast=currentscrolled
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:blockps},800);

}
  }

 dt= new Date();
  dt = dt.getTime();
}else{flag=0;}
scrolledlast=currentscrolled;
}}
```

Сделан он для того, чтобы сделать поблочный скролл- один div размером с экран монитора.
При быстрой и/или частой прокрутке экран начинает дёргаться - как этого избежать?

Ссылка на сайт : http://lendsale.ru/stackoverflow/

Comment: Попробуйте останавливать анимацию перед запуском. $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:0},800); и $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:blockps},800);

Comment: Не помогло или я не понял. Не могли бы Вы глянуть ? Сайт добавил в сам вопрос.

Comment: Везде где у вас .animate нужно попробовать добавить stop чтобы было .stop().animate Каждый раз когда вы вызываете animate создаётся новая анимация и становится в очередь, если объект уже анимируется stop() останавливает любую анимацию применяемую на объекте.

Comment: То есть вместо $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},800); нужно прописать $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:0},800);?

Comment: Да, я позже выложу пример как должен работать такой слайдер, недавно в проекте было.

Comment: В общем то заменил. На мышке не видно, а вот на тачпаде дёргается безумно. Буду благодарен за пример и буду ждать, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно разобраться, что именно не так с вашим кодом. Вот пример такого слайдера: https://jsfiddle.net/CLackyM/fcksq4L1/
Скорость реакции на окончание скролла вот здесь:

```
window.mainSliderScrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    window.goNearestSlide();
},500);
```

А скорость анимации вот здесь:

```
$('html').animate({
    scrollTop:o
}, 500,"easeOutQuad", function () {
    console.log('scrll complete');
});
```

Чтобы сделать кнопки вперёд назад можно создать переменную для хранения текущего слайда и через функцию window.goSlide(x) переключать слайды